# has no default constructor

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I keep getting an error which crashes my program.

"com.example.AutoResizeTextClock.AutoResizeTextClock has no default constructor"

I assume it is the android:name in my AndroidManifest.XML but I don't know what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

AndroidManifest.XML

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.AutoResizeTextClock" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".AutoResizeTextClock"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

activity_auto_resize_text_view.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="32dp"
android:background="#ff000000">

<com.example.android.clocktest.AutoResizeTextClock
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="Auto Resized Text, max 1 line"
    android:textSize="500sp"
    android:textColor="#fff44336"
    android:textFont=""
    /> <!-- maximum size -->


</LinearLayout>
```

AutoResizeTextClock.java

```
package com.example.android.clocktest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.TextClock;


public class AutoResizeTextClock extends TextClock {
    private interface SizeTester {
        /**
         *
         * @param suggestedSize
         *            Size of text to be tested
         * @param availableSpace
         *            available space in which text must fit
         * @return an integer < 0 if after applying {@code suggestedSize} to
         *         text, it takes less space than {@code availableSpace}, > 0
         *         otherwise
         */
        public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSpace);
    }

    private RectF mTextRect = new RectF();

    private RectF mAvailableSpaceRect;

    private SparseIntArray mTextCachedSizes;

    private TextPaint mPaint;

    private float mMaxTextSize;

    private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

    private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

    private float mMinTextSize = 20;

    private int mWidthLimit;

    private static final int NO_LINE_LIMIT = -1;
    private int mMaxLines;

    private boolean mEnableSizeCache = true;
    private boolean mInitiallized;

    public AutoResizeTextClock(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize();
    }

    public AutoResizeTextClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize();
    }

    public AutoResizeTextClock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        mPaint = new TextPaint(getPaint());
        mMaxTextSize = getTextSize();
        mAvailableSpaceRect = new RectF();
        mTextCachedSizes = new SparseIntArray();
        if (mMaxLines == 0) {
            // no value was assigned during construction
            mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        }
        mInitiallized = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(final CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
        super.setText(text, type);
        adjustTextSize(text.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextSize(float size) {
        mMaxTextSize = size;
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxLines(int maxlines) {
        super.setMaxLines(maxlines);
        mMaxLines = maxlines;
        reAdjust();
    }

    public int getMaxLines() {
        return mMaxLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSingleLine() {
        super.setSingleLine();
        mMaxLines = 1;
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSingleLine(boolean singleLine) {
        super.setSingleLine(singleLine);
        if (singleLine) {
            mMaxLines = 1;
        } else {
            mMaxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        }
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLines(int lines) {
        super.setLines(lines);
        mMaxLines = lines;
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
        Context c = getContext();
        Resources r;

        if (c == null)
            r = Resources.getSystem();
        else
            r = c.getResources();
        mMaxTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, size,
                r.getDisplayMetrics());
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
        super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
        mSpacingMult = mult;
        mSpacingAdd = add;
    }

    /**
     * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
     *
     * @param minTextSize
     */
    public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize) {
        mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
        reAdjust();
    }

    private void reAdjust() {
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    private void adjustTextSize(String string) {
        if (!mInitiallized) {
            return;
        }
        int startSize = (int) mMinTextSize;
        int heightLimit = getMeasuredHeight() - getCompoundPaddingBottom()
                - getCompoundPaddingTop();
        mWidthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft()
                - getCompoundPaddingRight();
        mAvailableSpaceRect.right = mWidthLimit;
        mAvailableSpaceRect.bottom = heightLimit;
        super.setTextSize(
                TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
                efficientTextSizeSearch(startSize, (int) mMaxTextSize,
                        mSizeTester, mAvailableSpaceRect));
    }

    private final SizeTester mSizeTester = new SizeTester() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSPace) {
            mPaint.setTextSize(suggestedSize);
            String text = getText().toString();
            boolean singleline = getMaxLines() == 1;
            if (singleline) {
                mTextRect.bottom = mPaint.getFontSpacing();
                mTextRect.right = mPaint.measureText(text);
            } else {
                StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, mPaint,
                        mWidthLimit, Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult,
                        mSpacingAdd, true);
                // return early if we have more lines
                if (getMaxLines() != NO_LINE_LIMIT
                        && layout.getLineCount() > getMaxLines()) {
                    return 1;
                }
                mTextRect.bottom = layout.getHeight();
                int maxWidth = -1;
                for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++) {
                    if (maxWidth < layout.getLineWidth(i)) {
                        maxWidth = (int) layout.getLineWidth(i);
                    }
                }
                mTextRect.right = maxWidth;
            }

            mTextRect.offsetTo(0, 0);
            if (availableSPace.contains(mTextRect)) {
                // may be too small, don't worry we will find the best match
                return -1;
            } else {
                // too big
                return 1;
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Enables or disables size caching, enabling it will improve performance
     * where you are animating a value inside TextView. This stores the font
     * size against getText().length() Be careful though while enabling it as 0
     * takes more space than 1 on some fonts and so on.
     *
     * @param enable
     *            enable font size caching
     */
    public void enableSizeCache(boolean enable) {
        mEnableSizeCache = enable;
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    private int efficientTextSizeSearch(int start, int end,
                                        SizeTester sizeTester, RectF availableSpace) {
        if (!mEnableSizeCache) {
            return binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
        }
        String text = getText().toString();
        int key = text == null ? 0 : text.length();
        int size = mTextCachedSizes.get(key);
        if (size != 0) {
            return size;
        }
        size = binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
        mTextCachedSizes.put(key, size);
        return size;
    }

    private static int binarySearch(int start, int end, SizeTester sizeTester,
                                    RectF availableSpace) {
        int lastBest = start;
        int lo = start;
        int hi = end - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            mid = (lo + hi) >>> 1;
            int midValCmp = sizeTester.onTestSize(mid, availableSpace);
            if (midValCmp < 0) {
                lastBest = lo;
                lo = mid + 1;
            } else if (midValCmp > 0) {
                hi = mid - 1;
                lastBest = hi;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
        }
        // make sure to return last best
        // this is what should always be returned
        return lastBest;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start,
                                 final int before, final int after) {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldwidth,
                                 int oldheight) {
        mTextCachedSizes.clear();
        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);
        if (width != oldwidth || height != oldheight) {
            reAdjust();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add an empty constructor.

Comment: @GabeSechan has rightly pointed out that you have major problems with your code. `AutoResizeTextClock` is not an `Activity` or its subclass but you're still adding it in you manifest in the `<activity>` tag.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is a bit confused.  In your manifest xml you call it an Activity, but your Java code is for a View.  These are two different things.  An Activity must derive from Activity (or a subclass of it) and must have a default constructor-  usually it has no constructors and lets the compiler generate a default one.  A View must have one of 3 constructors (at least) and generally has one that takes a Context and a AttributeSet.  Which is what your code has.  You need to create a real Activity and put this View into a layout to display.

Comment: I believe you are right. I modified some other code I found. However my understanding of android is still very limited and I am making mistakes. I will have to learn more about Activities before I proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Create a default constructor for your class that takes no parameters.

```
public AutoResizeTextClock() {

}
```

Comment: While you aren't wrong, if you look at his code he has major issues beyond that.  That won't be sufficient to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

[Default Constructors](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/systems/cluster/vac-7.0/html/language/ref/clrc15cplr376.htm):

> A default constructor is a constructor that either has no parameters,
>   or if it has parameters, all the parameters have default values. If no
>   user-defined constructor exists for a class A and one is needed, the
>   compiler implicitly declares a constructor A::A(). This constructor is
>   an inline public member of its class.

So just add:

```
public AutoResizeTextClock() {

}
```

Comment: That didn't work. I think there is more to it than just that.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above two comments:

Remember to init your context, attributeset and defStyle with default values or your base class won't be setup properly.

Comment: He can't.  His problem is he's confusing activities and views.  A view inflated from xml will get its parameters correctly set.  An Activity doesn't have one (in fact an Activity is a Context).

Comment: Ah. Thanks! It's generally good practice but I believe I missed that this was an android app. It must be late :)

Comment: @GabeSechan You are correct. I am clearly confusing activities and views. Looks like I still have a ways to learn before I can proceed.